# Bootstrap switch fails to work on Ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Following is the code that doesn't work with the data retrieved from different ***php page*** using ajax for multiple input(checkbox) elements having different *Name* but with same *Class* ***probeProbe***.

```
$(".probeProbe").each(function() {
var nami = $(this).attr('name');
$.get("processattend.php?init="+nami ,function(data){
    loly=(data==1)?true:false;
    alert(loly);
    });
   $("input[name='"+nami+"']").bootstrapSwitch('state',loly ,true);
});
```

If I place `true` or `false` inplace of variable ***loly*** it works , but with above code it fails and sometime shows correct and sometime wrong output.
The data returned from the php file is either **0 or 1** thereafter the code explains itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Can you try with this*

```
$(".probeProbe").each(function() {
var nami = $(this).attr('name');
$.get("processattend.php?init="+nami ,function(data){
    loly=(data==1)?true:false;
    alert(loly);
    $("input[name='"+nami+"']").bootstrapSwitch('state',loly ,true);
    });
});
```

Try to wait for the ajax result before init the bootstrapSwitch...

Comment: still no success , out of three inputs , 2 of them showed correctly but one ended up with uninitialised checkbox(no-bootstrap-checkbox)